# What consistency guarantees does a Google AppEngine task queue make?

Tags: google-app-engine, queue, task

What consistency guarantees does a pull queue make?

- Is it strongly consistent? ie: if a task has been added, then attempts to lease will see that task in exactly the position it was added.

if not, then:

- Is its ordering consistent? ie: if tasks A and B are added, in that order, then they will always be leased in that order.
- Does it have holes? ie: if tasks A, B and C are added in that order, will leasing sometimes return A, C ?

Or are there no guarantees, besides eventual consistency? ie: is it not really a queue at all, but just a loosely ordered collection of tasks?

( There is a previous related question here, but it's not asking quite the same thing:
[Is the Pull Queue in GAE exhibit consistent FIFO behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422094/is-the-pull-queue-in-gae-exhibit-consistent-fifo-behavior) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that any guarantees are made about order at a fine scale.  Order is broadly observed, and I have never set out to precisely answer this question, but I would not rely on it being absolutely maintained - even from a single source of tasks.

I know for certain that tasks with an assigned delay of just 1s can take many minutes to resurface on busy queues.  (By 'busy' I mean >1k leases/minute.)